# How do I display data for an embedded object in an embedded form using Silex and Symfony Forms?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, silex

I have a model in my application called `Content`.  This has three properties that are linked to another model called `ContentBodyType`.  This is to allow three sections of the content which are 'Banner', 'Summary' and 'Main'.

I have created a `FormType` for the `Content` model using SymfonyForms.  The following shows how this is built up:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $list = $this -> app['model.collection'] -> getList();

    $builder -> add('id', HiddenType::Class)
             -> add('displayname', TextType::Class, array("label" => "Friendly Name", "trim" => true))
             -> add('description', TextareaType::Class)
             -> add('collection', ChoiceType::Class, array(
               'choices_as_values' => true,
               "choices" => $list,
               "label" => "Collection"
             ))
             -> add('publish', ChoiceType::Class, array(
               "choices" => array('Yes' => true, 'No' => false),
               "choices_as_values" => true,
               "expanded" => true,
               "multiple" => false,
             ))
             -> add('homepage', ChoiceType::Class, array(
               "choices" => array('Yes' => true, 'No' => false),
               "choices_as_values" => true,
               "expanded" => true,
               "multiple" => false,
             ))
             -> add('startdate', DateTimeType::Class, array("widget" => "single_text", "format" => "dd-MM-yyyy"))
             -> add('expirydate', DateTimeType::Class, array("widget" => "single_text", "format" => "dd-MM-yyyy"))
             -> add('type', ChoiceType::Class, array(
               "choices_as_values" => true,
               "choices" => array(
                 'News' => "news",
                 'Page' => "page",
                 'Pinned' => "pinned",
                 'Blog' => "blog",
                 'Slider' => "slider"
               ),
               "label" => "Type"
             ))
             -> add('main', new \Turtle\Form\Type\ContentBodyType())
             -> add('banner', new \Turtle\Form\Type\ContentBodyType())
             -> add('summary', new \Turtle\Form\Type\ContentBodyType())
             -> add('save', SubmitType::Class)
             -> add('cancel', ButtonType::Class);

    // only add the name field if this is a new template
    if (!$this -> content || null == $this -> content -> getId()) {
      $builder -> add('name', TextType::Class, array('label' => 'Name'));
    }
  }
```

When the application loads up the form it shows the data from `Content` model in the correct fields, however the ones that are part of the nested form are not displayed.

Now I know that this is because for each of 'banner', 'summary' and 'main' I am creating a new instance of the `ContentBodyType` form object.  However I cannot work out how to pass in the object to this so that it does not have to be created.

The form is created using the following code:

```
   public function edit(Request $request, $id) {

     // Get the entity from the datastore for the specified id
     if ($id == "new") {
       $item = new \Turtle\Model\Entity\Content(); 
     } else {
       $item = $this -> app['model.content'] -> getById($id) -> first();
     }

     if (!$item) {
       return "notthere";
     }

     // Build the form
     $type = new \Turtle\Form\Type\ContentType($this -> app, $item);

     $form = $this -> app['form.factory'] 
                   -> createBuilder(
                         $type, 
                         $item, 
                         array(
                           'action' => $this -> app['url_generator'] -> generate(
                             'content_update', 
                             array(
                               'id' => $item -> getId()
                             )
                           )
                         )
                       ) -> getForm();

     // process the form to see if it has been submitted or not
     $form -> handleRequest($request);

     snip ....
```

I am sure that this is a simple fix, but I just cannot see what it is.

Thanks, Russell

Answer (score 0):

I have worked this out.  I had forgotten that when I create an instance of the `ContentBody` I made the constructor accept arguments one of which was the item that had been loaded from the datastore.

```
class ContentType extends AbstractType {

  private $app;
  private $item;

  public function __construct($app, $item) {
    $this -> app = $app;
    $this -> item = $item;
  }

  snip....
```

So as I have the item as a property in the class, I can then pass this to the `ContentBodyType` in the `buildForm` function.  So now the three sections of the form get created thus:

```
-> add('main', new \Turtle\Form\Type\ContentBodyType($this -> item -> getBanner()))
-> add('banner', new \Turtle\Form\Type\ContentBodyType($this -> item -> getSummary()))
-> add('summary', new \Turtle\Form\Type\ContentBodyType($this -> item -> getMain()))
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it because I am sure that at some point in the `SymfonyForms` code the model is passed to the FormType, but this solved the issue I had.